# Batch file not working: Spaces in path

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
set RF_PROPERTIES="%ARCOT_HOME%\conf"
dir %RF_PROPERTIES%
if not exist %RF_PROPERTIES%
goto NO_RF_PROPERTIES
```

The ARCOT_HOME variable above has spaces. The dir command works and lists the files, but the if command fails with "The syntax of the command is incorrect.". Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way round:

```
set RF_PROPERTIES=%ARCOT_HOME%\conf
dir "%RF_PROPERTIES%"
if not exist "%RF_PROPERTIES%" goto NO_RF_PROPERTIES
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if not exist "%RF_PROPERTIES%" GOTO NO_RF_PROPERTIES
GOTO OK

:NO_RF_PROPERTIES

GOTO END

:OK

GOTO END

:END
```

Comment: No, using set RF_PROPERTIES=%ARCOT_HOME%\conf instead of set RF_PROPERTIES="%ARCOT_HOME%\conf"
fails to find the path as there are spaces in between and it says No such file. That's why I tried putting double quotes.

Comment: It complains "Syntax of the command is incorrect" when I put quotes in the if not exist condition:                                     if not exist "%RF_PROPERTIES%"

Comment: @Hugh Darling did you ADD the GOTO statement on the same line? Just like I and David did?

Comment: I'm not relying just on my printed messages, so you don't have to think I'm printing wrong diagnostics. The if not exist command itself prints "The system cannot find the path specified.". even though the file exists, when I don't use quotes, and when I use quotes I get an error message that syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @Hugh Darling I can repro your error if I only have IF NOT EXIST "%RF_PRP%" on one line, then it outputs: The syntax of the command is incorrect. That is beacuse IF is defined as IF [NOT] EXIST filename command. You cannot put the command on the next line, it needs to be on the same line. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks so much both of you.

Comment: @Hugh If we helped you then please consider up-voting the helpful answers and accepting the most helpful. Doing so is the "currency" of Stack Overflow. I've ensured that you have enough reputation to vote up.